# How to connect to Heroku Database using SQLAlchemy without database url?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to develop a simple python web application on Heroku and I'm trying to connect to the Heroku Postgres database. I've managed to connect, but only through using the database url Heroku provides:

```
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

app = Flask(__name__)
engine = create_engine('postgres://XXXXXXX@XXXXcompute-1.amazonaws.com:XXX')
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()
```

Is there a way to connect to the Heroku database through my python code without having to include the exact url? Thanks!

Comment: I was having trouble connecting to Postgres and this solved the problem for me: https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-heroku/